# How to categorized results from SQL, display 6 columns and set colorize on every category

Tags: php

I would like to ask for help on how to achieve this. I have this code below that pull records from DB and display it in 6 columns.

What I want to achieve is that, I want to display results on 6 columns but I want to categorize and set different color on every category.

let say i want to display the whole set of fruits starting from letter A with 6 columns with colors of gray, then below all letters starting with B with 6 columns with white color on background then below is C with gray colors in 6 columns. thanks.

```
<?php
fruits = $stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER by fruit_id ASC");
$fruits->execute();
$cols = 6;

do {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $cols; $i++) {
        $row = $fruits->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($row) {
            $fruit_id = $row['fruit_id'];
            $fruit_name = $row['fruit_name'];
?>

<td>
  <table>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td>
        <?php echo '<input type="checkbox" id="fruit_id[]" name="fruit_id[]" value="' . $fruit_id . '"/>' . $fruit_name . "\n"; ?>
      </td>
      <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</td>
<?php
        } else {
            echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }
    }
} while ($row);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in the database:

```
SELECT fruits.*,if(@evenodd>0,'grey','white') AS color, @evenodd:=-1*evenodd AS dummy FROM (@evenodd:=1) as init, fruits ORDER by fruit_id ASC
```

Comment: regarding the SQL query above, how can i make it work with my code? i tried to replace that SQL but it doesn't work. please advice thanks.

Comment: Hi Eugen, I can't make it work when i use your suggestion in my code. please advise thanks